# Problem integrating esp01 with arduino mega

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

Can someone please help me in connecting the ESP 01 wifi module with Arduino mega. I have looked at multiple resources online, none of which worked for me.

The esp 01 module just heats up and doesn't respond to AT commands.

Can someone provide me some good resources to look upon?

Please guide me.

Comment: ESP-01 is a 3V3 device, while Arduino Mega is 5V. How do you connect with ESP-01? What code you run to test AT Command response from ESP-01?

Comment: ESP --> ARDUINO MEGA
GND --> GND
Vin --> 3.3V
ENABLE --> 3.3V
TX --> SERIAL 1 RX
RX --> SERIAL 1 TX (3.3 v by using voltage divider Circuit)